# Notepad++ Find lines beginning with characters RS and at column number 500 Insert 00 (double zero)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a large dataset designed with multiple dimensions.  For example:  Dimension one begins with RS, Dimension two begins with RW, Dimension three begins with RT, Dimension four begins with RC.  With each line that begins with RW I need to insert 0000000000 (10 zeroes) to occupy character positions 474 to 484.  How would I go about finding each row that begins with RW and inserting 10 zeros at column 474?   All other text needs to stay put.

For example:

example current: RW123456 <10 blank spaces> with text preceding and following.

example desired: RW123456 0000000000 without interrupting preceding and following text.

Comment: you want to replace those 10 blank spaces or keep those but insert 10 zeroes beforehand ?

Comment: I have updated the answer have a look at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Update:

search by :

```
^(RW.{471}).{10}
```

replace by this:

```
\10000000000
```

You can try this:

```
^(RW.{498})
```

and replace by this:

```
\100
```

Explanation:

1. `^` start of a line
2. RW starts with RW
3. `.{498}` followed by 498 characters as RW occupies 2 character.
   change it to your need
4. `(RW.{498})` capture this full inside `()` to mark as group 1

replacement:

```
replace the full matched string by group 1+00
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NjMdsR/3)

Comment: Hmm .. did not work.  Row Example:  RW123456 ............... traveling to position 474.......... insert zeros at character position 474 through 484.  So in techno speak ... Find rows / records beginning with RW and at character position 474 insert ten zeros.

Comment: example current:   RW123456                                      <10 blank spaces>

Comment: example desired:  RW123456                                      0000000000

Comment: You wanted to insert 00 but why are you replacing 10 blank spaces by 10 zeroes !?

Comment: file format requirement of entity on receiving end of file

Comment: but  this is not what you wrote in your original post, so plz update the question with some expected input output in order to address your updated problem

Comment: What is the significance of '471' in the find?  Why wouldn't the find look for 474?